# Include an unknown amount of external images in a report?

Tags: .net, asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I am building a report that needs to include photographs, I have no way of knowing how many photos will be taken but they are stored on a file server under folder named after the ID of the report being generated. How would I go about including these in an RDLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple to include images in report if you know quantity and filenames: [MSDN How to: Add an Image (Image Wizard)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156388(SQL.90).aspx)

But in your case if you don't know how many images should be displayed, you have options:
- save image file names in DB and select them with sql from report
or
- create web service to gether image file names from directory and pass it in report as a datasource. [Reporting Services: Using XML and Web Service Data Sources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129.aspx)

Next in report use Table or List, place Image there and set url/path to Image from datasource field.

Comment: I ended up having my code scan the file system and add entries to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a PHP guy so my answer needs to be filtered, but in PHP you'd do a directory reading and then review each file in the directory to make sure it was a suitable image type for including.

opendir()
readdir()

and the a for a while loop to review the file name extensions to make sure you're including only images.

Comment: I know file i/o, the problem is with RDLC more than anything, it's kind of like crystal reports.

Comment: Maybe this link will help 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067(VS.80).aspx

Comment: It does not... all the msdn documentation assumes you know how many images, exactly where they are located and the filename. The only condition I meet there is the second.